# Is this matrix differentiation derivation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra, trace

I am trying to find derivative of this quantity but in my result the dimensions don't match. Any inputs will be helpful.

**$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\left\|F(w)-\beta D^{\top} Z\right\|_{F}^{2}\right)$$**

$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\left\|F(w)-\beta D^{\top} Z\right\|_{F}^{2}\right)   
=& \, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\left\|F(w)-\beta D^{\top} Z\right\|_{F}^{2}\right)\\
  =& \, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(Tr\left[ (F(w)-\beta D^{\top} Z) \, (F(w)-\beta D^{\top} Z)^{\top}\right] \right)\\
  =& \, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(Tr\left[ \left(F(w)\,F(w)^{\top}\right)- 2\,F(w)\left( \beta D^{\top} Z\right)^{\top} + \left(\beta D^{\top} Z Z^{\top} D \beta^{\top} \right) \right] \right) \\
  =& \, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}Tr\left[ F(w)\,F(w)^{\top}\right] - 2 \, C_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial w} Tr\left[\,F(w)\left( \beta D^{\top} Z\right)^{\top} \right]\\
  =& \, \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial w}F(w)\right)\,F(w)^{\top} - 2 \, C_1 \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial w} \,F(w) \right)\left( \beta D^{\top} Z\right)^{\top} \\
  =& \, \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial w}F(w)\right)\, \left(F(w) -  \left( \beta D^{\top} Z\right)\right)^{\top} \\
  =& \, \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial w}F(w)\right)\, \left(F(w)^{T} -   Z^{\top}D \beta^{T}\right)
 \end{split} 
\end{equation} $$

Is the above derivation correct ? I think dimensionality of gradient doesn't match !!!
$$ D_{d \times m}, Z_{d \times l}, F(w)_{n \times l}, w_{d \times n}, \beta_{n \times m} $$

Gradient of "w" should be of same dimension as "w" which is (d X n) but the resultant is coming out to be tensor. Note that "F(w)" has soft-max probabilities for "Z"  predicted using  "w"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
M &= \beta D^TZ \\
W &= w &&\big({\rm Uppercase\,for\,matrices}\big) \\
A &= (F-M) \quad&\implies\quad&dA = dF \\
}$$
You haven't told us anything about the function $F(W)$,
so I'll assume you don't need help calculating its fourth-order tensor gradient
$$\eqalign{
\Gamma_{ijk\ell} &= \p{F_{ij}}{W_{k\ell}} \\
}$$
The double-dot product notation for the trace of matrices
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
is easily extended to higher-order tensors, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \Gamma:X \quad&\implies\quad Y_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{\ell=1}^q \Gamma_{ijk\ell}X_{k\ell} \\
Z &= Y:\Gamma \quad&\implies\quad Z_{k\ell} = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n Y_{ij}\Gamma_{ijk\ell} \\
}$$
Write the trace using the above notation, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A:A \\
d\phi &= 2A:dA = 2A:dF = 2A:\Gamma:dW \\
\p{\phi}{W} &= 2A:\Gamma \\
}$$
It's easy to see that the gradient of the trace (with respect to $W$) has the same dimensions as $W$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learn a lot from you

Comment: What is the significance of "G" ?  and "F" is a output of neural network.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got $$ F = \Gamma : W $$

Comment: I don't understand your question. That line describes the mechanics of the double-dot product between a fourth-order tensor $(\Gamma)$ and an arbitrary matrix -- I've changed the name of the matrix, in case that was a source of confusion.